# Acceder a un array bidimensional mediante un desplegable

Tags: php

Tengo un array bidimensional con el que quiero crear un select desplegable en el cual al elegir una de las distintas opciones, me devuelva una tabla con los datos dados por la opción elegida tal que así:

[image: Resultado]

Código:

```
    <?php

$arrayResultados =  array 
         ('Libre'=>  array('No Presentados'=>12,'Suspenso'=>10,'Aprobado'=>6,'Notable'=>3,'Sobresaliente'=>1),
          'On-line'=> array('Suspenso'=>26,'Aprobado'=>25,'Notable'=>22,'Sobresaliente'=>27),
          'Presencial'=>array  ('Suspenso'=>30,'Aprobado'=>25,'Notable'=>37,'Sobresaliente'=>28,'Matrícula de Honor'=>9)
          );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
        <select name="desplegable">
        <option value="todas" selected="selected">Todas</option>
        
<?php
    foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice => $valor)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$indice."'>".$indice."</option>";
    }
?>      
</select>
<input type="submit" name="envio" value="Aceptar">
    </form>
    

<?php
        if(isset($_POST["envio"]))
        {
            $listaAlum=[];
            foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice => $valor)
            {
                foreach ($valor as $detalles => $numero)
                {               
                        if(isset($indice[$_POST["desplegable"]]))
                        {   
                            $listaAlum[$detalles] = $numero;
                        }
                }       
                    
                        
            }
            
            echo "<h3>Seleccion: ".$_POST["desplegable"]."</h3>";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($listaAlum);
            echo "</pre>";
        }




?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Esta parte de código: "if(isset($indice[$_POST["desplegable"]]))" no me funciona y si no lo quito del código no me guarda nada en el array.

No consigo hacer que me muestre todos los valores cuando elijo la opción "todas", me saltan varios errores (Undefined index:) y me suma los valores numéricos mas veces de la cuenta.
Lo que hago en el siguiente código es un if donde si elijo la opción "todas" añada al array $listaAlum la suma de los valores numéricos.

```
if($_POST["desplegable"]=="todas") //cuando elija la opcion todas
                        {
                            foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice => $valor)
                            {
                                foreach ($valor as $detalles => $numero)
                                {   
                                    $listaAlum[$detalles] = $numero;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Como tendría que ponerlo?

Cuando le doy a todas este es el resultado que me da, no entiendo el por que me da ese resultado (son los valores del ultimo valor del array) ni tampoco el por que no me guarda el valor "No presentado".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿cuál es el problema en concreto? ¿hay algún error? ¿qué error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Ya encontré la forma de hacerlo, lo voy a actualizar, gracias.

Comment: @JohnDoe la eventual solución va como respuesta por favor y no en la pregunta

Comment: perdon, voy a editarlo

Comment: @BetaM yo diría más bien que esta pregunta debería ser borrada. A no ser que OP edite completamente la pregunta, de modo **que el problema se entienda claramente** y luego **explique la solución**, indicando por qué eso ha resuelto el problema. Una pregunta que no se entiende con una auto-respuesta para decir *resolví el problema* **no aporta nada al sitio**, pues Stackoverflow no es un foro.

Comment: Lo entiendo @A.Cedano y tienes razón, solo quise que tuviera presente donde debe publicar cada cosa.

Comment: estoy editando para explicarlo mejor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actualizo con la solución completa:
He sustituido la parte del isset para que al elegir una opción compruebe si la opción elegida se encuentra en el array, si se encuentra añado al array "$listaAlum" todos los valores del opción elegida.

Para la opción "todas" simplemente recorro el array y guardo las categorías en otro array para después recorrerlo e ir acumulando todos los alumnos en cada categoría.

```
    <?php

$arrayResultados =  array 
         ('Libre'=>  array('No Presentados'=>12,'Suspenso'=>10,'Aprobado'=>6,'Notable'=>3,'Sobresaliente'=>1),
          'On-line'=> array('Suspenso'=>26,'Aprobado'=>25,'Notable'=>22,'Sobresaliente'=>27),
          'Presencial'=>array  ('Suspenso'=>30,'Aprobado'=>25,'Notable'=>37,'Sobresaliente'=>28,'Matrícula de Honor'=>9)
          );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
        <select name="desplegable">
        <option value="todas">Todas</option>
        
<?php
    foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice => $valor)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$indice."'>".$indice."</option>";
    }
?>      
</select>
<input type="submit" name="envio" value="Aceptar">
    </form>
<?php
$arrayCalificaciones=array();

        if(isset($_POST["envio"]))
        {
            $listaAlum=[];
            
            foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice => $valor)
            {
                foreach ($valor as $detalles => $numero)
                {                                                           
                    if($_POST["desplegable"]==$indice)
                        {
                            $listaAlum[$detalles] = $numero;
                        }                                           
                }
            }   
            
                        if($_POST["desplegable"]=="todas") //cuando elija la opcion todas
                        {
                            foreach ($arrayResultados as $indice=>$vector)
                            {
                                foreach($vector as $categoria=>$numero)
                                {
                                    if (!array_key_exists($categoria,$listaAlum))
                                    {
                                        $listaAlum[$categoria]=$numero;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $listaAlum[$categoria]=$listaAlum[$categoria]+$numero;
                                    }
                                }
                            }                       
                        }

            echo "<h3>Seleccion: ".$_POST["desplegable"]."</h3>";
            if(sizeof($listaAlum)>0)
            {
                echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Calificacion</th><th>Alumnos</th></tr>";
                foreach ($listaAlum as $calificacion => $alumnos) 
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$calificacion."</td><td>".$alumnos."</td></tr>";
                }
                    echo "</table>";
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "No hay datos"; 
            }
        }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál era el problema y por qué esta es la solución? Considera que las preguntas que planteas en SO podrían servir en un futuro a otros usuarios con un problema parecido. Esta es una de las principales características de este sitio. Actualmente tu pregunta y tu solución sólo son entendidas por ti y no aportan nada a futuros usuarios. Por otra parte, aunque lo hayas resuelto, si se entiende el problema y la solución, otros usuarios con más experiencia podrían enriquecer tu código, señalándote otras formas mejores de resolverlo, parcheando errores de seguridad, etc.

Comment: Creo que ha quedado todo bien explicado, únicamente me falta la parte de elegir la opción "todas" para que me muestre todos los datos que aun no consigo que me funcione. Perdón por las molestias. PD. Cuando consiga que me funcione lo de todas edito la respuesta.

Comment: No parece ser algo tan complicado, pero lo estás haciendo complicado, creo, porque **no te has detenido a explicar el problema de una forma sencilla** (eso se refleja desde un principio en la pregunta, por eso mi primer comentario en ella pidiéndote aclaraciones). Si logras explicar con simplicidad lo que quieres podremos ayudarte a simplificar/optimizar tu código, el cual, para mi gusto, marea demasiados los datos. Por experiencia te digo que explicar el problema es una etapa importante, verbalizando el problema entiendes todo mejor y a veces hasta das con la solución.

Comment: Creo que ahora ha quedado bien explicado todo.

Comment: Ahora se entiendo mejor. Aunque hay algo que no queda claro todavía. ¿Hablamos de dos select dependientes? O sea, en un `select` escoges por ejemplo `Libre` y hay otro `select` que se llenaría con los valores propios de `Libre`? Fíjate que incluso esto sería mejor resolverlo en el cliente, usando atributos `data-*` o de otro modo, para poder actualizar los `select` sin tener que recargar la página. Es lo que sospechaba, entendiendo mejor el contexto queda claro que tu código puede ser mejorado/optimizado, por eso es tan importante explicar el problema de la forma más clara posible.

Comment: No no, solo hay un select y cuando eliges en ese select "Libre" te muestra los datos de "Libre". Esa parte ya me funciona, la que no consigo que me funcione es al darle a "todas" y que sume para cada apartado el numero de alumnos que hay.

Comment: No entiendo mucho. ¿Si eliges `Libre` entonces no puedes volver atrás (revertir esa selección) y vacías el mismo select para poner en él los option de `Libre`?. Este tipo de cosas funcionan generalmente con select dependientes, de modo que puedas cambiar si te equivocas de option. Lo de *sumar*  es un detalle adicional que tampoco logro entender. Como ya dije antes, si verbalizas el problema tendrás más claridad para resolverlo, creo que te estás liando mucho y todo porque no te has detenido a explicar/entender el problema.

Comment: A ver, tengo una lista desplegable con los valores: Todas, Libre, On-Line y Presencial, si elijo Libre, me muestra los datos de libre, si elijo Presencial, se elimina la tabla Libre y muestra los datos de Presencial, nada mas. El desplegable se rellena con datos del array y los datos que muestra también son sacados del array. En la pregunta inicial he subido imágenes que muestran el funcionamiento.

Comment: O sea, al seleccionar `Libre` u otro lo que ocurre es que se llena otro elemento (una tabla por lo que parece), con los options de `Libre`. ¿He entendido bien? Pues como sospechaba desde el principio, esto es más simple de hacer de lo que crees e incluso podría quedar reflejado en el cliente mediante atributos `data-*` o de otro modo, así no hay que recargar la página para actualizar tu tabla cada vez que se cambie entre `Libre` u otras de las opciones. Todo esto es perfectamente manejable desde Javascript (o sea, del lado del cliente) sin necesidad de molestar al servidor en cada cambio.

Comment: El funcionamiento es muy simple, solo necesito saber como hacer para que cuando seleccione "todas" me muestre los valores sumados para cada elemento, no se como se hace ni encuentro nada donde poder guiarme, solo puedo usar php.

Comment: ¿Por qué sólo puedes usar PHP, es un ejercicio y te exigen que debe ser en PHP? Este tipo de problemas deberías resolverse en el cliente, usando Javascript. No tiene sentido resolver esto en PHP, teniendo que recargar la página una y otra vez.

Comment: Si, solo debe hacerse en php además no hace falta recargar la pagina, cada vez que eliges una opción se borra la tabla anterior y se sustituye por la nueva. Copia el código en un archivo y lo pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de cosas **deben resolverse siempre en el cliente**. La función del servidor es darte los datos que allí residen, pero una vez con los datos, los cambios dinámicos debes trabajarlos en el cliente.

¿Cuál es la razón de esto? Que si reflejas los cambios dinámicos en el servidor, **cada vez que haya un cambio tendrás que volver al servidor para reflejar esos cambios sin ninguna necesidad**, y ese ir al servidor tiene un costo altísimo.

Imagínalo así, para que se entienda: los datos están en el servidor (en Australia) y tú estás en París (el cliente). Cada vez que el `select` cambie en el cliente (en París) te pagas un billete de avión París-Australia para ir a Australia a comparar datos que ya tienes a mano en París. ¿Acaso no es absurdo? ¡Si tienes los datos en París no vayas a Australia a comprobar esos datos que ya tienes! ¡Vas a terminar arruinado!

Otra cosa es que algún dato de esos cambie, teniendo un valor distinto en el servidor... entonces sí deberías ir de nuevo al servidor a buscar los nuevos datos. Pero no es el caso aquí, `$arrayResultados` tiene unos datos fijos que, una vez recibidos en el cliente puedes trabajarlos.

Este código, contrario a lo que puedes pensar, no recarga a nadie, sino que distribuye de manera justa las responsabilidades. Imagina una aplicación con millones de usuarios, todos esos millones de usuarios generando tráfico aéreo Resto del Mundo-Australia y calculando en Australia todo lo que se debería calcular en el resto del mundo. En fin... un desastre.

Aparte de eso, el código funciona mucho más rápido al estar distribuido. El servidor de Australia podría terminar cayendo ante tanto tráfico.

Observa la solución propuesta, trabajando la lógica desde el cliente. Aquí, la variable `mData` representaría los datos que vendrían en `$arrayResultados`, cuando el servidor te suministre esos datos entrará en descanso, y le tocará a cada cliente trabajar. Es así como funcionan las aplicaciones modernas.

```js
/*
  mData sería tu array, que podrías mandar al cliente
  con un simple  echo json_enconde($elArray);
  Aquí lo declaramos a mano para fines de prueba
*/
let mData = `{"Libre":{"No Presentados":12, "Suspenso":10, "Aprobado":6, "Notable":3, "Sobresaliente":1},
"On-line":{"Suspenso":26, "Aprobado":25, "Notable":22, "Sobresaliente":27},
"Presencial":{"Suspenso":30, "Aprobado":25, "Notable":37, "Sobresaliente":28, "Matrícula de Honor":9}
}`;

/*Creamos un JSON con los datos recibidos del servidor*/
let mJson = JSON.parse(mData);

/*Referencia a los elementos*/
let mSelect = document.querySelector('#mSelect');
let mTable = document.querySelector('#mTable');
let tBody = document.querySelector("#mTable tbody");

/*Llenamos de forma dinámica los option*/
for (var key in mJson) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = key;
  mSelect.appendChild(option);
}

/*Escuchamos los cambios del select*/
mSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  let mKey = event.target.value;
  /*Aquí, cuando sea todas recogemos y sumamos los datos*/
  if (mKey === "Todas") {
    var mObj = {};
    for (i in mJson) {
      for (key in mJson[i]) {
        if (mObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          mObj[key] += mJson[i][key];
        } else {
          mObj[key] = mJson[i][key];
        }
      }
    }
  /*O bien construimos la tabla con el option seleccionado*/  
  } else {
    var mObj = mJson[mKey];
  }
  fillTable(mObj);

});

/*Esta función es para llenar la tabla de forma dinámica*/
function fillTable(mObj) {
  /*Limpiamos el tbody de la tabla*/
  document.querySelectorAll("#mTable tbody tr").forEach(function(e) {
    e.remove()
  });
  
  /*Recorremos el objeto para llenar la tabla*/
  for (var key in mObj) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let tdA = document.createElement("td");
    let tdB = document.createElement("td");
    tdA.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
    tdB.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mObj[key]));
    tr.appendChild(tdA);
    tr.appendChild(tdB);
    tBody.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="mSelect">
  <option>-Seleccione-</option>
  <option>Todas</option>
</select>

<table id="mTable" class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero como te comenté no me sirve que esté hecho en js, pude resolverlo, actualizo mi respuesta con el ejercicio terminado.

Comment: @JohnDoe no le veo mucho sentido a hacer esto en PHP, pero bueno, cada uno es libre de programar como quiera. Me alegro de que lo hayas "resuelto", pero habría que preocuparse por la optimización.

Comment: es que el ejercicio hay que hacerlo en php para aprender php, no me vale pedir el ejercicio en php y hacerlo en js, no tiene ningún sentido.